# Measuring features effect and importance in Partial Least Square (PLS) regression

Tags: correlation, feature-importances, partial-least-squares, partial-dependence-plot

**Context:** it is possible to assess features importance and effect for a model using model-independent scoring techniques such as Partial Dependence (PD) profile, Acculumated Local Effect (ALE) profile, H-Statistic and measure of increase in loss after feature permutation.
PLS is an algorithm that allow to start from a dataset with correlated features and transform it in a space of lower dimension trying to reduce correlation between the "new" dimensions.

My goal is to compare feature importance and effect of a PLS, a LASSO and a Random Forest model using a common technique.

**Problem:** the scoring techniques rely on the fact that features are not correlated (except for the ALE); they are based on *ceteris paribus*, i.e. changing the value of a feature while keeping the others constant for a given individual. I am worried to make a mistake using them for the PLS.

**Question:** how to use partial dependence & co. techniques for the PLS algorithm?

**Remarks:**

- For other reasons, I had process through iterative feature eliminations for the LASSO and the Random Forest models so the question does not apply to them here.
- I would like to avoid using the ALE profile. If I could use the partial dependence and related measures like the H-Statistic and Individual Conditional Expectations (ICE) profile (also named Ceteris Paribus profile), it would make the identification of interactions much easier.

**Source:**

Explanatory Model Analysis: https://ema.drwhy.ai/

Interpretable Machine Learning: https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/

Disclaimer: question crossposted on Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/637639/227668) as I do not know which community is the most relevant for it.